# Python Array error: "list indices must be integers or slices, not list"

Tags: python, list

I'm new to Python and trying to add two strings to a key-value array.

Here's my code:

```
import os
from numpy import genfromtxt
import re



script_dir = os.path.dirname(r'C:/Users/Kenny/Desktop/pythonReports/')

my_data = genfromtxt('allreports.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None)


pattern_id = re.compile(r'(?<=eventid\=)(.*)(?=&key)', flags=re.DOTALL)
pattern_key = re.compile(r'(?<=key\=)(.*)(?=&cb)', flags=re.DOTALL)

id_key = {}

for row in my_data:
    eventid = pattern_id.findall(row.decode('utf-8'))
    eventkey = pattern_key.findall(row.decode('utf-8'))
    id_key[eventid] = eventkey

    print(id_key)
```

This basically takes a url, and extracts two things from it. I want to then take those two things and create an associative array (key/value) with those two pieces of information.

Example data is: {123456, 412F5BFE1D8A33BC}

And there are hundreds of urls, therefore the reason for an array.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 20, in <module>
    id_key[eventid] = [eventkey]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Thanks for any help with this, and in case it's needed, I'm using Python3.

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. I think what you are looking for is Dictionary so replace ` id_key = []` with ` id_key = {}`

Comment: `re.findall` returns a list, not an integer

Comment: Lists are not associative arrays. Lists are sequences. If you want an associative array, that's what dicts are for.

Comment: @Ludisposed oops that's how I originally had it `id_key = {}`, I had altered for testing purposes. @Vinícius Aguiar thank you, I didn't know re.findall returned a list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30890707/python-typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you want an associative array, so use a dict instead of a list. Second, `findall` returns a list and you want the element.

```
id_key = {} # replaced [] with {}

for row in my_data:
    eventid = pattern_id.findall(row.decode('utf-8'))[0] # note added [0]
    eventkey = pattern_key.findall(row.decode('utf-8'))[0]
    id_key[eventid] = eventkey
```

But if you're going for style points I'd recommend a dict comprehension

```
id_key = {pattern_id.findall(row.decode('utf-8'))[0]: 
          pattern_key.findall(row.decode('utf-8'))[0] for row in my_data}
```

or one more way

```
def id_and_key(line):
    return (pattern_id.findall(line)[0],  
            pattern_key.findall(line)[0])

id_key = dict(id_and_key(row.decode('utf-8')) for row in my_data)
```

Comment: Great, this works! I originally had `id_key = {}` but used [] for testing and forgot to change back when pasting in code. Thanks for pointing out `re.compile` returns a list, that makes sense now.

Comment: For `id_key` can you explain or link to docs they `{item1:item2 for row in my_data}` works? Having the for loop as part of the declaration?

Comment: @Kenny sorry I meant to say `findall` returns a list.  You'll want to understand [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), before you try to understand [dict comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/#examples)